# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'right'

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

i am very new to SQL, spent hours searching but all the articles point to more or less same

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
RIGHT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

Bellow is my code, but honestly not sure what am i doing wrong here.

```
  "SELECT * FROM user_private_store WHERE store_type=@STORE_TYPE " +
     "RIGHT JOIN user_private_store_items " +
     "ON user_private_store.id = user_private_store_items.id";
```

I want to join both tables via ID, keep the id from left and take other parameters from right table user_private_store_items

i get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'right'

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` is an **operator** in the `FROM` clause.  `WHERE` is a clause that follows the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to `LEFT JOIN` instead. Much easier to understand.

Comment: Order **must be**: `SELECT ... FROM ..... (JOINS) ..... WHERE .....` you have the `WHERE` *before* the `JOIN` - that won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `where` clause after the joins:

```
"SELECT * FROM user_private_store s " +
"RIGHT JOIN user_private_store_items i " +
"ON s.id = i.id " +
"WHERE store_type=@STORE_TYPE"
```

Notes:

- table aliases make the query easier to read and understand. I modified you query to use them
- you would need to prefix `store_type` in the `where` clause with the table it belongs to, to avoid ambiguity
- avoir `select *`; better enumerate all the columns that you want to select

Comment: Thank you so much for the beginner tips aliases actually look amazing, reference to code "where" belongs to user_private_store only so i start to get error on story_type Invalid column name 'store_type

Comment: Sure but what about error i commented above "Invalid column name 'store_type"

Comment: And since you're concatenating together those strings into a SQL statement, you should **use at least one space** at the end of each line ! Otherwise you get funny errors when your statement looks like ` ..... _store sRIGHT JOIN ..... iON .....` and so forth

Comment: Managed issue i did WHERE s.store_type